# Why does the npm package listing for Preact say it's over 1MB if it's supposed to be 3kb?

Tags: reactjs, npm, bundler, preact

I've been looking into using Preact to build embeddable/distributable widgets, and one of the benefits that is touted everywhere is that the build size is supposed to be tiny - just 3kb, [as it says on their homepage](https://preactjs.com/).

But if you look at the NPM packages, Preact says `Unpacked Size: 1.26MB` while React says `Unpacked Size: 291kb`. Which to me seems like React is almost 5 times smaller than Preact.

Then, if you look at [this data gathered on the size of JS Frameworks](https://gist.github.com/Restuta/cda69e50a853aa64912d), it says that Preact when minified is 16kb. It does say 4kb gzipped, but as far as I know the gzip compression isn't something included as standard in the build process for frontend frameworks, so I don't know where or how Preact got that 3kb figure.

Can anyone tell me how the package sizes listed can differ so much?

Comment: What does the NPM package actually contain? That should clearly indicate where this “extra” space is going. Most size numbers, such as quoted at the end, refer to the (core script) size “as expected to fetched by a client in a release build”, not the NPM package content itself or any ancillaries.

Comment: As far as compressed (minified) vs GZIP, the former is the *file size on disk* and the latter is the *on wire size sent to the client* when served using HTTP a compressing Content-Encoding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding — it is relatively uncommon to explicitly pre-compress HTTP resources and often requires additional server configuration (to indicate which  pre-compressed binary resources should be served with the appropriate Content-Type, as opposed to a binary transfer).

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing size on disk of the module off of NPM and bundle size.

The distributed library contains a lot of code that you will not use at one time. It is distributed in a number of module formats for each subpackage (we'll get to that in a second) so you always have a format available to you that works in your environment, be that UMD, ESM, etc. These are essentially duplicates of the code, which increases the size on disk without ever being relevant to the bundle size.

The distributed files also contain a lot of content that is dev-only, like the source code and sourcemaps. Sourcemaps, if you're unfamiliar with them, help you debug built (minified and/or mangled) code. You'll likely disable sourcemaps in your production site (though this is a matter of opinion, there certainly are reasons to keep them enabled) so these files are largely irrelevant.

So Preact comes with a number of submodules, or packages that ship alongside the main library. `preact/compat` and `preact/hooks` are examples of this. If you're not using what the submodule offers (full React compatibility in the case of the former, hooks for the latter) then all of that content is irrelevant as well. Each submodule also includes the source code, source maps, and different module formats. These are distributed with the main library for the user's ease of use; no need to install multiple packages.

Lastly, the magic of treeshaking and bundlers. You likely won't use every last piece of code that Preact ships with and bundlers will accordingly remove those unused pieces. This of course does not apply in bundler-less scenarios, but it's pretty common nowadays to use a bundler.

> as far as I know the gzip compression isn't something included as standard in the build process for frontend frameworks

Gzip, and more recently Brotli, absolutely is a standard in serving web content. Doesn't matter what the size on the disk is, it matters what gets sent over the internet on request. Preact is roughly ~4kb.

If you'd like a quick peek at what Preact distributes (and what is making up that distribution size), [check this out](https://www.runpkg.com/?preact@10.6.1/package.json). Lets you inspect the distributed files of the package.

Comment: Thank you, this allays my concerns about using the framework. I'm not sure if it's the right answer, though, because it's all theoretical and not really something I can test unlike, say, a block of code. So for now I've left an upvote.

Comment: @crevulus Why can't you test it? Copy the `dist/preact.module.js` from [here](https://www.runpkg.com/?preact@10.6.1/dist/preact.module.js) (this is an ESM build of the module, works in all modern browsers with just a <script> tag) and paste it into a Gzip/Brotli compressor like [this](https://dafrok.github.io/gzip-size-online/) to see the size. Gzip is a bit worse than Brotli, and no tree-shaking is performed, but it absolutely is something you could easily test.

Comment: As for it being "the right answer", this is most certainly how we measure it. Yes, this isn't something you can just eyeball from NPM but that's the nature of the beast. Distributing a single 3kb gzipped file would be suitable for very few people to actually use.